# Why do fixed length char arrays in D allow direct string assignment?

Tags: d

Strings in D are just immutable arrays of chars. For example.

```
immutable(char[]) baba = "Baba Yaga";
```

such that trying something like

```
char[] baba = "Baba Yaga"; // ERROR!
```

would throw an exception `Error: cannot implicitly convert expression "Baba Yaga" of type string to char[]`. You need to copy the string first using its `.dup` property.

```
char[] baba = "Baba Yaga".dup;
```

However, why does the following work?

```
char[9] baba = "Baba Yaga";
```

Can you please explain what is going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple: the compiler knows the size of the string literal and knows the size of the static array and can see that they can simply be copied over, so it does. Then since it knows it is a new copy, immutable need not apply since that only applies to references to the original.

With `char[] baba =`, the compiler doesn't know all that - in your case it is trying to assign a *reference* to the original string, meaning the mutable/immutable mismatch applies, so it makes you explicitly clarify that you wanted a copy.